# How can i include self in rolling() and what should i initialize it with?

Tags: python, self, rolling-computation

```py
df['ma50'] = pd.Series.rolling(window=50,center=False).mean(df['bidclose'], 50)
df['ma200'] = pd.Series.rolling(window=200,center=False).mean(df['bidclose'], 200)
plots = df[['bidclose', 'ma50', 'ma200']].plot(subplots=False, figsize=(10, 4))
plt.show()
```

...leads to...

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-60-744ccc8ffc60> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 df['ma50'] =pd.Series.rolling(window=50,center=False).mean(df['bidclose'], 50)
      3 df['ma200'] = pd.Series.rolling(window=200,center=False).mean(df['bidclose'], 200)
      4 plots = df[['bidclose', 'ma50', 'ma200']].plot(subplots=False, figsize=(10, 4))
      5 plt.show()

TypeError: rolling() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: `pd.Series` is a _class_. You need to call `rolling()` on an _instance_ of that class, you can't just call it directly on the class itself. (Instances have an implicit `self`).

Comment: so, once you have an object of type `Series`, you then call `rolling()` _on that object_. But you need to make a specific Series object first.